# How to Combine 3 Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

**Hello Community**

I just want to ask about my code. i just want to combine my 3 variable

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT disease,age,SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalM`, SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalF` FROM mdr where disease = '$diseaseselection' GROUP BY disease , age");
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tabx[]=$row['age'];
    $taby[]=$row['totalM'];
    $tabz[]=$row['totalF'];

}
$tableau=array_combine($tabx,$taby,$tabz);

foreach($tableau as $key=>$value){

    $string[]=array('age'=>$key,'totalM'=>$value,'totalF'=>$value);

}

echo json_encode($string);
```

It works fine with this code. with 2 variable. and i want it to be done by tree variable

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT disease,age,SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalM`, SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalF` FROM mdr where disease = '$diseaseselection' GROUP BY disease , age");
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tabx[]=$row['age'];
    $taby[]=$row['totalM'];

}
$tableau=array_combine($tabx,$taby);

foreach($tableau as $key=>$value){

    $string[]=array('age'=>$key,'totalM'=>$value);

}

echo json_encode($string);
```

**Here is my EXPECTED output**

```
{ age:'0-1', totalM:2, totalF:1},

{ age:'1-4', totalM:1, totalF:0},

{ age:'10-14', totalM:0, totalF:1},

{ age:'15-19', totalM:0, totalF:1},

{ age:'5-9', totalM:0, totalF:3},

{ age:'55-59', totalM:6, totalF:0}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you exactly want to achieve. Please post input and expected output and also errors/issues

Comment: Array combine is merging 2 arrays to make a key-value pair. You really don't need to use in this case. Do you want to create a JSON string 3 or more keys?

Comment: i already added my expected output above thanks

Comment: i just want to combine my 3 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT disease,age,SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalM`, SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `totalF` FROM mdr where disease = '$diseaseselection' GROUP BY disease , age");

$chart_data = '';

$data = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = [
        'age' => $row['age'],
        'totalM' => $row['totalM'], 
        'totalF' => $row['totalF']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use multiple array, you can get desired result with multi dimensional array.

```
$key = 0;
$output = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $output[$key]['age'] = $row['age'];
 $output[$key]['totalM'] = $row['totalM'];
 $output[$key]['totalF'] = $row['totalF'];
 $key++;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: above code is an example, you have to figure it out using that way

Comment: yes I  agree that i used in appropriate name for array variable, I should change that

Comment: @B001ᛦ well, I guessed that question asker will get the point, I should have given full example :).